# Error "Microsoft SQL Native Client error '80040e37'"

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

After moving my database and web site for another server I got the error Microsoft SQL Native Client error '80040e37'.
   The problem occurs in a query inside an asp file that do not have schema.tablename, only tablename. But I do not want to include "schema" in all queries right now. 
   All updates were installed and the default schema for my user is correct.
   SQL Server is configure to mixed mode and to accept both windows authentication and sql server authentication.
   Softwares: IIS 6, Sql Server 2005.

Comment: did you move from the same version of sql server?

Comment: Yes, Sql Server 2005 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was "Orphaned" logins. The solution was to run the stored procedure sp_help_revlogin, copy its results and run them in the new server.

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_help_revlogin]
```

Example Result:

```
CREATE LOGIN [exampleLogin] WITH PASSWORD = 0x0100E634633EB1BF18E HASHED, SID = 0x840D462D26543B4FB71234B36137A131, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [yourDB], CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```